# How to show that $ \sum_{n=0}^{2j} \frac {z^{n}}{\zeta^{n+1}} =\frac {z^{2j+1}-\zeta^{2j+1}}{(z-\zeta)\zeta^{2j+1}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am studying  some types of convergent sequences.
I know that $ \sum_{n=0}^{2j} z^{n}=\frac {z^{2j+1}-1}{z-1} $, but I am struggling with how to show that :

$$\sum_{n=0}^{2j} \frac {z^{n}}{\zeta^{n+1}}=\frac {z^{2j+1}-\zeta^{2j+1}}{(z-\zeta)\zeta^{2j+1}}.$$

When I examined this formula with $j=1$ and $j=2,$ it is works but how can I prove this formula for all values of $j=1,2,\dots$ or where can I find a list of table show this?

Comment: You can factor $\zeta$ from the denominator to get the classical geometric series, of which you know its closed form.

Comment: Write $\frac{z^n}{\zeta^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{\zeta}\big(\frac{z}{\zeta}\big)^n$, then use the formula, where you put $\frac{z}{\zeta}$ in place of $z$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been completely answered by the comments.

Comment: Btw, when $z=\zeta,$ this sum is equal to $2j+1.$

Comment: Consider the known relation, as also mentioned in the question, but i am changing that $z$ into an $X$ to have a better way (didactically) to replace variables below:$$1+X+X^2+\dots+X^{2j}=\frac{X^{2j+1}-1}{X-1}\ .$$Now plug in $X=z/\zeta$ (assuming $X\ne 1$, i.e. $z\ne \zeta$) into the formula. Is it clear now?!

Answer (score 1):

As @Anne Bauval points out, this question has been answered in the comments.

You are already aware of the geometric series formula. @dan_fulea suggests you change the variable from $z$ in your expression to $X$:
$$
    \sum_{n=0}^{2j} X^n = \frac{X^{2j+1}-1}{X-1}
$$
Your expression contains a geometric series with $X=\frac{z}{\zeta}$ in it. So
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{2j} \frac {z^{n}}{\zeta^{n+1}}
    &= \frac{1}{\zeta}\sum_{n=0}^{2j} \left(\frac{z}{\zeta}\right)^n \\
    &= \frac{1}{\zeta} \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{z}{\zeta}\right)^{2j+1}-1}{\frac{z}{\zeta}-1} \\
    &= \frac{\left(\frac{z}{\zeta}\right)^{2j+1}-1}{z-\zeta} 
       \cdot \frac{\zeta^{2j+1}}{\zeta^{2j+1}}\\
    &= \frac {z^{2j+1}-\zeta^{2j+1}}{(z-\zeta)\zeta^{2j+1}}
\end{aligned}$$